# Capacitor changing output voltage from 12v to 20v

Tags: power-supply, dual

I have a transformer with two output coils I have wired them together in series and used the connection between them as 0v and used the other two leads in a diode bridge rectifier. Without any filter caps, I get +12v on one rail and -12v on the other. However when I add in any kind of cap for filtering my voltage jumps up to 20v.

The parts I am using are largely salvaged; but the only part that I have little to no info on is the transformer. It takes US AC voltage, (110-120) but I don't really know what it's intended output is.

I am very much in the learning stage with this stuff so odds are I have made a dumb mistake, but hey, that's why my parts are salvaged. No cost, none lost. Am I right?

EDIT: To clarify I am going for a dual power supply. With 0v and +/-Voltage. I would prefer +/-12v because 20 volts pushes the limit of some of my other external components, but I can change things if needed.

Comment: Please note that the question you have actually asked (Am I right?) does not seem like the question you want answered. So edit to ask a technical question.

Comment: Was going to write an answer, searched for an illustration. Found the illustration on stackexchange..

Comment: re-measure it under load. use a voltage regulator if you want a fixed output. they also cut down a lot on ripple anyway.

Comment: I have a voltage regulator (lm7805) that I have setup with variable voltage. And adding a cap after it still changes the voltage.

Comment: @EllaRobinson If a cap changes the voltage you might more than just DC getting through the regulator. Check the AC voltage across the capacitor (with a meter in AC mode). You need to filter the voltage before the regulator, so the regulator sees DC not AC. You'll get a better answers if you provide a schematic with the tool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without a filter capacitor, your meter will read some form of average of the rectified waveform, which will vary from Zero to the AC peak voltage every half-cycle.

With a filter capacitor, and little or no load on the power supply, the capacitor will charge up to nearly the peak AC voltage, and will provide nearly pure DC at that voltage, causing your meter to read a higher voltage than it did without the filter capacitor.